# JS - закачка файла

Tags: javascript

Можно ли сделать так: как только веб-документ передается на компьютер пользователя, запускается js-скрипт, который тайком от пользователя закачивает на его компьютер бинарник и запускает его на выполнение? Как реализовать такое? Сам JS не изучал, мне главное узнать, возможно ли то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, так сделать нельзя, браузеры не предоставляют доступа к файловой системе пользователя, иначе это было-бы большой дырой безопасности.

Comment: А в вопросе про использование браузера ничего и не сказано :)

Answer (score 0):

"Тайно скачивает"... Даже знать не хочу зачем.

Наверное можно, если на ноде крутится скрипт-предатель, могущий открыть лазейку в систему.
Если "тайно скачать и запустить с правами на выполнение" - легальное действие, заморочьтесь инструкцией по установки ноды, запуска скрипта, его написанием.
Иначе проще 0-day найти.

Answer (score 0):

На js скорее всего только с использованием сплоитов. А по делу надо создать бинарник замаскированный под что то обычное который скачает юзер и запустит на своем пк (под каким либо предлогом). Либо создавать склейку. Только так.